# No content displayed for a low quality review item when the question has been deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, deleted-questions, low-quality-posts

For this [low quality review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/66230), there is no content displayed. Usually 10k+ users are able to see the deleted posts, but for this review there is no content displayed.

Why is the content not displayed for this review item?

> [image: SS]

---

Few more examples [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/64601), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/64947), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/65122), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/66155)

Comment: Looks like a bug where if the question has since been deleted, it just doesn't show anything there for anyone. It's exhibiting the same behavior for all past tasks where the question is now deleted (only checked LQP queue though).

Comment: This was the post under review (10K only) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331980/how-to-change-lookup-value

Comment: FYI, the post wasn't shown, directly after I reviewed it, too (was not deleted then), @animuson. I was on mobile then (so I didn't want to file a bug report) and forgot about this until now.

Comment: If the post is no longer reviewable, why is the review queue showing it in any way at all? Shouldn't it simply be removed from the queue automatically upon deletion?  (Or is that what the bug is here—that it still has an entry?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems the bug had been fixed sometime before.

Now, the 10k+ user can able to see the deleted posts in the low quality review posts.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: can see the question]